# Finding the value of a bivariate function $f(a,b) = ab^2$

Tags: functions

Given $f(a,b) = ab^2$, find $f(s, t+h) - f(s, t)$ ?

I have decided to approach it this way. Is it correct?

$$
\begin{align*}
f(s, t+h) - f(s, t) &= s(t+h)^2 - st^2 
\\&=s(t+h-t)^2
\\&=sh^2
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Unless you're in a ring of characteristic 2, $(a + b)^2\neq a^2 + b^2$ in general. Your solution isn't valid because the manipulations you've done with squares aren't valid: try expanding $(t + h)^2$ first and then simplifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No...wait

I think it's like this...I just naively took the square off...

$$
\begin{align*}
f(s, t+h) - f(s, t) &= s(t+h)^2 - st^2 
\\&=s[(t+h)^2 - t^2] \tag{new working}
\\&=s[(t+h+t)(t+h-t)]\tag{diff of sq.}
\\&=s[(2t+h)(h)]
\\&=sh(2t+h)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: There you go; this is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's better.